# WireGuard Throughput Issues

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables, wireguard

I'm having quite an odd issue with WireGuard performance between a VyOS router [LTS 1.3.3] and a Cloud VPS [Debian 12] acting as a CHR.

I have a publicly facing `/29` routed to the CHR via GRE, at an MTU of `1440` with MSS clamping using `iptables`:

```
post-up iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o gre1 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

- The `/29` is split into `/32`'s, routed to remote endpoints over WireGuard *(MTU `1420`)*

I've measured the actual physical paths that transport the WireGuard connection and have easily reached >3gbit/s in testing, but when I push bandwidth through WireGuard, I only get 45mbit/s downstream, but full link speed upstream:

- After rebooting VyOS, I am pushing 200mbit/s downstream; any ideas as to what could cause this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How about this:
Try mtu 1300 , mss 1260

Answer (score 0):

How about this: Try to set mtu with value 1300 , mss with value 1260 on both sides(vyos and other server). I'm sure it will be work just as I did.

You can try to install vyos on the cloud vps.
Actually you can install vyos on any cloud or any vps. VyOS is a great virtual routers which I like it the most.

```bash
#vyos 1.3.3
#set wireguard mtu value
set interfaces wireguard wg101 mtu '1300'
#Set mss for wireguard mss 
set firewall options interface wg101 adjust-mss '1260'
```